# Polarity of electrolytic capacitor

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

Electrolytic capacitors can only be biased by one polarity of the voltage.

I am having a hard time understand how to connect a electrolytic capacitor to a voltage source.

The symbol of a electrolytic capacitor is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLEHdD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and when I see a electrolytic capacitor I have something like this:

[image]

Now there is a strip with a - sign on it so I guess that side of the capacitor will go to the lower voltage correct?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=electrolytic+capacitor+symbol&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: As others have noted, the symbol you show is incorrect. That is the symbol for a variable capacitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, correct. On the picture you posted the dashes indicate the negative terminal of the capacitor, and the other is the positive terminal.

Comment: The negative terminal is also the shorter leg (assuming no one has been at it with side-cutters yet!).

Answer (score 1):

The symbol you have shown is incorrect.

Here's the correct one.

[image]

On the component, however, the -ve terminal is marked.

Comment: This is the correct symbol, but often the '+' is omitted.

Comment: 62 years ago the positive terminal of an electrolytic capacitor was marked "+" and the negative terminal was not marked.